# R plots some unicode characters but not others

Tags: r, unicode, cairo

our sysadmin just upgraded our operating system to SLES12SP1. I reinstalled Rv3.2.3 and tried to make plots. I use `cairo_pdf` and try to make a plot with the x-label being `\u0298` i.e. the solar symbol, but it doesn't work: the label just comes out blank. For example:

```
cairo_pdf('Rplots.pdf')
plot(1, xlab='\u0298') # the x-label comes up blank
dev.off()
```

This used to work, but for some reason it does not anymore. It works with other characters, e.g.

```
cairo_pdf('Rplots.pdf')
plot(1, xlab='\u2113') # the x-label comes up with the \ell symbol
dev.off()
```

When I just paste in the solar symbol, i.e.

```
plot(1, xlab='ʘ')
```

then I get the warning

```
Warning messages:
1: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ʘ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ca>
```

The machine is German, but I am using the US English UTF-8 locale:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Any tips on how I can get the solar symbol to appear?

Answer (score 4):

Note: I suppose with a new system you should first do:

```
capabilities() #And see what the result for cairo is.
```

A couple of ideas although one of them requires knowing what fonts you are using so the output of `l10n_info()$MBCS` and `names(X11Fonts())` might be  needed.

Option 1) The Hershey fonts have all the astrological signs as special escape characters. Page 4 of the output of :

```
 demo(Hershey)   # has \\SO as the escape sequence for the "solar" symbol.
```

So looking at the code for the `draw.vf.cell` function we see that it's using the `text` function to plot those characters and therefore using it to label an axis will require adding `xpd=TRUE` to the arguments:

```
plot(1, xlab="") ; text(1, .45, "\\SO" , vfont=c("serif", "plain"), xpd=TRUE )
```

[image]

Option 2) find the solar symbol in the font of your choice. You might try setting the font to something other than "Helvetica". See `?X11` that has a section on Cairo fonts. The `points` function's help page has a function called TestChars that lets you print character glyphs in various fonts to your output device. In this case your output device might be either `cairopdf` or `x11`. On my device (the Mac fork of UNIX) the Arial font has this output:

```
   png(type="cairo-png");plot(1, xlab="\u0298");dev.off()
```

My observation over the years of similar questions leads me to believe that Cairo graphics are more reliably cross-platform. But since R can be compiled without cairo support, it's not a sure thing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your text editor is using latin1, therfore you would send latin1 characters to your console.

Look at the encoding

```
Encoding('ʘ')
```

and / or try

```
plot(1, xlab=iconv('ʘ', from='latin1', to="UTF-8"))
```

but be carefull the encoding could change while coping.
If you use Notepad++ you can convert in the text editor between the different encodings.

Comment: Also, > Encoding("ʘ")
[1] "UTF-8"

Comment: Then I don't know but maybe the issue is that you don't use german as your local. `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")`
I use R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) and have as locale

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_AT.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_AT.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

and it works. But I don't know for sure.