# Using subscript in ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggpubr

I'm trying to plot some data, one of my experimental groups is named SiO₂. I load a .txt datasheet using read.table and then I change the col names with colnames()<-.

```
colnames(cells_df2) <- c("ID","Ctrl","SiO\u2082","pSLG","fSLG")
```

Here is a subset of my data.

```
head(cells_df2)
ID     Ctrl  SiO2     pSLG     fSLG
1  1  5.68565  9.48 14.77580 33.04500
2  2  6.79996 32.00 14.35580 33.04500
3  3 21.77180  8.14 16.49780  7.61765
4  4 16.30750  8.14  1.87977  7.61765
5  5 11.16920 19.20  5.54189 28.47990
6  6 11.31430  8.26 15.59490 28.47990
```

Then, I `gather`ed of this data.frame

```
Cells_tidy3<-gather(cells_df2,"group","ym",-ID)
  ID group       ym
1  1  Ctrl  5.68565
2  2  Ctrl  6.79996
3  3  Ctrl 21.77180
4  4  Ctrl 16.30750
5  5  Ctrl 11.16920
6  6  Ctrl 11.31430
```

Finally I plot them

```
ggboxplot(Cells_tidy3,"group","ym")
```

[image]

I have tried to use `expression`, `parse`, `stringi` package with scarce results.

If I ask for `capabilities()`

```
jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp 

TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE`    TRUE 

sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS   profmem

TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE

cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 

TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Then I tried:

```
png()
ggplot(az, aes(x = "SiO\u2082", y = value)) + 
geom_boxplot() +
xlab("")
dev.off()
```

Which lead to this graph

[image]

Comment: Check your data with `str(az)` to see if the numeric column was read in as numeric or as factor.

Comment: this is the result

data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SiO2 : Factor w/ 1 level "ciao": 1 1 1 1
 $ value: int  1 2 3 4

Comment: So you are plotting a boxplot (not a barplot) of a factor, `ciao` with just one level, all its values are equal. That's why you are getting that plot.

Comment: @RuiBarradas if you want I can use the real data set instead of this example

Comment: my question is how to obtain SiO₂ instead of SiO□

Comment: OK, sorry, I had misunderstood, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. It uses `ggplot` followed by `geom_boxplot`, not `ggpubr::ggboxplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

az <- subset(iris[5:4], Species == "virginica")
az[[1]] <- droplevels(az[[1]])
names(az) <-c("SiO\u2082","value")

ggplot(az, aes(x = "SiO\u2082", y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

With package `ggpubr`, the problem is how you `gather`ed the data. The column `"value"` became a column with value of the previous column name in `az`, which was `"ciao"`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggpubr)

azz <- az %>% gather(group, key, -value)
ggboxplot(azz, x = "group", y = "value")
```

[image]

Comment: @pietroesposito No, not as a comment, in the question, please. And see the edit with `ggpubr`.

Comment: If I use your codes both the one with ggplot and ggpubr I obtain SiO□

Comment: @pietroesposito As you can see, both plots display the subscript correctly so there must be something with your system. What does `capabilities()` return? And if you write to a device with, say, `png()` before the plot and `dev.off()` right after, what's in the graphic file?

Comment: I re-edit my question with the information you asked for.

Comment: @pietroesposito This seems to be a system thing. Try installing X11? Also, see if these posts can help: [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/unicode-symbols-in-r/), SO [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682707/r-plots-some-unicode-characters-but-not-others) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e).

Comment: unfortunately I didn't menage to install X11, I looked on the web and I didn't find anything